# key value pattern with multiple criteria using positive look overhead

Tags: javascript, regex

i try to format text which contain key value pairs (which i have multiple match criteria). I try with positive look overhead like this but i should match with exact one word as value

```
/(?=firstname|lastname)(.*)/gi
```

search text something like this

```
khjkhkj firstname: 'hello' jlkjkjkl
uhziuuj firstName 'hello' jkljljkkj
ugujgjg firstname='hello' oljkjlkjl
hkhjhkj firstName = 'hello' jljlljj
hjkhjkh firstname = hello jljkkljlk
khjkhkj lastname: 'world' jlkjkjkl
uhziuuj lastname 'world' jkljljkkj
ugujgjg lastName='world' oljkjlkjl
hkhjhkj lastname = 'world' jljlljj
hjkhjkh lastName = world jljkkljlk
```

Comment: Do you mean to get what is after `firstname` / `lastname`? `/(?:fir|la)stname[\s:=']*([^'\s]*)/gi`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxGFK6/1).

Comment: Regular expressions are surrounded by forward slash, noth backslash.

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew your solution is perfect, is it possible to select all words inside ' ' (quotes) because sometimes we may have `firstname: 'hello world' `

Comment: You'd probably need [two groups](https://regex101.com/r/LxGFK6/2). If there are single quotes, capture what's inside to **group 1**, else capture first word to **group 2**. If single quotes should go into the capture, use [one group](https://regex101.com/r/LxGFK6/3).

Comment: I added an answer, please check and let know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: thank you @bobblebubble this is more close to what i want

Comment: @Urock Then you may also use `/(?:fir|la)stname[=:\s]+('([^']*)'|\S+)/gi` without redundant capturing group and a `\S` rather than `\w` to match any non-whitespace chars. If you need to restrict `\S`, use e.g. `[^\s'<>]` that will match any char but a whitespace, `'`, `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?:fir|la)stname[\s:=']*([^'\s]*)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxGFK6/1). The value you need is in Group 1. Add a `\b` word bounary if necessary before `(?:fir|la)`.

**Details**

- `(?:fir|la)` - either `fir` or `la`
- `stname` - a literal text
- `[\s:=']*` - 0 or more whitespaces, `:`, `=` or `'`
- `([^'\s]*)` - Capturing group 1: 0 or more chars other than `'` and whitespaces.

See JS demo:

```js
var s = "khjkhkj firstname: 'hello' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj firstName 'hello' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg firstname='hello' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj firstName = 'hello' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh firstname = hello jljkkljlk\nkhjkhkj lastname: 'world' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj lastname 'world' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg lastName='world' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj lastname = 'world' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh lastName = world jljkkljlk";
var rx = /(?:fir|la)stname[\s:=']*([^'\s]*)/gi;
var m, res = [];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Or, using the `matchAll`:

```js
const s = "khjkhkj firstname: 'hello' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj firstName 'hello' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg firstname='hello' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj firstName = 'hello' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh firstname = hello jljkkljlk\nkhjkhkj lastname: 'world' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj lastname 'world' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg lastName='world' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj lastname = 'world' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh lastName = world jljkkljlk";
const rx = /(?:fir|la)stname[\s:=']*([^'\s]*)/gi;
let results = [...s.matchAll(rx)];
console.log(Array.from(results, m => m[1]));
```

Another alternative is to capture `'...'` or a string of non-whitespace chars after the words and punctuation:

```js
var s = "khjkhkj firstname: 'hello' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj firstName 'hello' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg firstname='hello' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj firstName = 'hello' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh firstname = hello jljkkljlk\nkhjkhkj lastname: 'world' jlkjkjkl\nuhziuuj lastname 'world' jkljljkkj\nugujgjg lastName='world' oljkjlkjl\nhkhjhkj lastname = 'world' jljlljj\nhjkhjkh lastName = world jljkkljlk";
var rx = /(?:fir|la)stname[=:\s]+('([^']*)'|\S+)/gi;
var m, res = [];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
    if (m[2] !== undefined) {
        res.push(m[2]);
    } else {
        res.push(m[1]);
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pnhlT/2).